# Erro na criação de chave estrangeira no MariaDB

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira, mariadb, engine, innodb

Ao tentar criar a tabela brinquedo, aparece o seguinte erro:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `brinquedos`.`brinquedo`
>   (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Segue o código:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categoria (
  categoria_id SERIAL,
  categoria_nome VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (categoria_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX categoria_nome_UNIQUE (categoria_nome ASC));


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS brinquedo (
  brinquedo_id SERIAL,
  brinquedo_descricao VARCHAR(180) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  brinquedo_imagem_url VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
  brinquedo_preco DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
  brinquedo_detalhes VARCHAR(180) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  brinquedo_categoria_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  brinquedo_marca VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (brinquedo_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX brinquedo_imagem_url_UNIQUE (brinquedo_imagem_url ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_brinquedo_categoria
    FOREIGN KEY (brinquedo_categoria_id)
    REFERENCES categoria (categoria_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Essa query funcionava no mysql, criei a meses atrás em um trabalho da faculdade, mas agora estou usando o MariaDB e está dando esse erro! 
Eu não entendo muito das peculiaridades do MySQL e do MariaDB. No MySQL eu usava a engine default InnoDB. Na documentação do MariaDB a engine default é InnoDB também, então estou usando InnoDB (eu acho).

Desde já agradeço a quem me ajudar.

Comment: SERIAL é do PostgreSQL

Comment: Chegou a testar o que foi respondido abaixo de por `brinquedo_categoria_id BIGINT` **`UNSIGNED`** `NOT NULL` ?

Comment: SERIAL funciona no MariaDB, a primeira tabela é criada com sucesso!

Comment: UNSIGNED, funcionou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Falta um `UNSIGNED` em `brinquedo_categoria_id` já que na tabela original foi definido `SERIAL`, que também não pode ser negativo.

Comment: Opa! Eu demorei para responde porque tive que fazer outras coisas aqui, mas sua solução funcionou: brinquedo_categoria_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL.
Era esse o problema, obrigado! Eu não sei porque tem um voto negativo na sua resposta!